# send string with two parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I have this code, but this line has some problem.

```
 var dataString = 'name='+name&'id='+id;
```

what is sent (firebug):

```
'id ' id
'name' name
```

The line above works correctly if i do:  `var dataString = 'name='+name;`
However, i need to pass two parameters. What is the correct way to do that?

**code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".vote").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var dataString = 'name='+name&'id='+id;

            if (name == 'up') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {

                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `&` goes in the string.`'name='+name&'id='+id;` should really be `'name='+name+'&id='+id;`

Comment: BTW, in an event handler `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do:

```
 var dataString = { name: name, id: id}
```

instead of

```
 var dataString = 'name='+name&'id='+id;
```

So that you are sure that the supplied values are correctly URI encoded.

Comment: this is the right answer - it ensures that the supplied values are correctly URI encoded.

Comment: @loops It's clean and as Alitak pointed out, you are confident that the values are URI encoded correctly

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var dataString = 'name='+name+'&id='+id;
```

Instead of

```
var dataString = 'name='+name&'id='+id;
```

The & should be inside '', and you need extra + to concat "name" variable and '&id=' string. So this should work.

**UPD:**

You can also do:

```
var dataString = { name: name, id: id }
```